# Is there a way to have a swing gui automatically go full screen?

Tags: java, swing, 2d

Is there a way to do that without having the user type in their resolution manually? Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: I use `setExtendedState( this.getExtendedState()|JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH );`

Answer (score 2):

Use **frame.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);**  to make your Swing gui to full screen. refer [Oracle doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setExtendedState%28int%29) for more information

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setExtendedState%28int%29

Answer (score 0):

If you mean real full screen (not maximized window), then try `setFullScreenWindow(Window w)` method of `GraphicsDevice` class.

It is not supported in all systems. Your program can check it by `isFullScreenSupported()` of `GraphicsDevice` class.

It is more than 10 years when I used this, but if I remember correctly, There is no need to tell resolution to `GraphicsDevice` object before entering to the full screen mode. Display will keep the current resolution.

At least there is function `getDisplayModes()` in `GraphicsDevice`. So your program can select suitable resolution from the list of supported resolution. So there is no need to ask resolution from users.

More information [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/exclusivemode.html).